# DropdownList of ExposedDropdownMenu does not update

Tags: android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I am using a Exposed dropdownlist in the application which should work like Spinner but when the
new data is attached to the adapter (data downloaded from server)it does not show the updated data instead previous data is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called `notifyDataSetChanged` or `notifyItemRangeInserted` after changing adapter data?